# What is the meaning of numpy reduceat() in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new in Python and I read at this moment just the tutorial.

I am confused about the `reduceat()` function.

I saw the example:

```
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7])[::2]
```

and result is:

```
array([ 6, 10, 14, 18])
```

How does it come out? Can some one explain for me?

Comment: actually I read it, but don't understand...

Comment: I thought, the indices[::2] should be[0,2,4,6] isn't it? The result after add() should be [ 0,  5,  3,  8,  6, 11,  9, 14], so, the result should be [0,3,6,9]

Comment: The array `indices` is interpreted (in a strange way) to define contingent intervals in array `a`, as follows: each consecutive pair of elements specifies a slice (i.e. a range of `indices`). It is circular, i.e. the last element of `indices` is paired back with first element. Each element in the `indices` participates in two pairs (two slices). Note that as usual, the range excludes the last index (i.e. the second element in the pair).

Then for each range (sub-array) specified by each such pair of indices, the "reduce" is applied separately. e.g. the elements in each slice are added up.

Comment: ... Example application 1: When we need to partition `a` into arbitrary non-overlapping arrays based on the partitioning specified using the `indices`. In such cases, the elements in the `indices` are sorted.

Comment: ... Application 2: Examples for which the array `indices` is not sorted are difficult to imagine. Unless the cases in which the `reduceat()` call is followed by `[::2]`. This applies the `reduce` on a set of arbitrary contingent subarrays of `a` by non-overlapping pairs of indices in `indices`. For example `np.add.reduceat(a, [start1,end1, start2, end2, start3, end3, etc])[::2]`. The `[::2]` is used because each element in `indices` should not participate in two pairs. Each index is either specifying the start or the end of a range (each index is one end of a pair of indices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sort of like a rolling apply, see:

```
In [59]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,4])
Out[59]:
array([ 6, 22])

In [65]:    
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[4,1])
Out[65]:
array([ 4, 28])

In [66]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,5])
Out[66]:
array([10, 18])

In [64]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[5,2])
Out[64]:
array([ 5, 27])

In [61]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,6])
Out[61]:
array([14, 13])

In [67]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[6,3])
Out[67]:
array([ 6, 25])

In [62]:
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[3,7])
Out[62]:
array([18,  7])
```

If you want just the 1st value, you can get it done in just one shot:

```
In [63]:    
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7])
Out[63]:
array([ 6,  4, 10,  5, 14,  6, 18,  7])
```

Answer (score 12):

The above answer is right but fails to explain what .reduceat is actually doing!
basically it is returning the sum of the elements that lie in the sliced array

for Example:

```
array = np.arange(10)
indices = np.array([1,3,4,5])
output = numpy.add.reduceat(array,indices)  
print(output)
```

OUTPUT:
[ 3  3  4 35]

What is happening behind the scenes is, it is applying the .reduce() repeatedly over the array like shown below :

```
print("Step1 : ", np.add.reduce(array[1:3]))
print("Step2 : ", np.add.reduce(array[3:4]))
print("Step3 : ", np.add.reduce(array[4:5]))
print("Step4 : ", np.add.reduce(array[5:]))
```

and appends the results of each step to a list and displays the result! Hope you understood what actually happens when you call numpy.add.reduceat() function!
I am not saying that the above answer is wrong, just providing another explanation to understand the function better!
Hope this helps! Thank you!

Comment: so what happens when those indices are not in ascending order?

Comment: It'll still work the same way, the indices need not be ordered in a particular fashion! ... I have taken the indices in Ascending order cuz it is easier to explain!    if you consider indices (5,4,3,1) you would get an output of [5,4,3,45].   this is a brief explanation, if you still didn't get it I can give you a detailed explanation!. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand it. Why is np.add.reduce(array[5:4]) == 5? shouldn't it be []? And actually, it's 0. I just checked. So why don't you get [0,0,0,45] if this is the only logic it follows? Instead you seem to get np.add.reduce(array[5:6]) which is 5. but why? there is no 6.

Comment: @Adarsh_V_Desai As Jim pointed out, it still needs further explanation. Please, provide us with more detail. I too fail to understand it.

Comment: @Jim From the numpy documentation: if indices[i] >= indices[i + 1], the i-th generalized “row” is simply array[indices[i]]. It means that for descending indices it just returns the value at the slice's left index. So you were correct, it indeed returns np.add.reduce(array[5:6]).

Comment: @Ladislav Ondris So essentially there is no added functionality in using indices that are not in ascending order and it only creates head scratching to the reader of the code. So don't do it, i guess...

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled to understand the example and I feel there is still something missing in both the posts which is partially explained in some comments so let me try to explain it as well.

#### General functionality

As stated in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html),

> For i in range(len(indices)), reduceat computes ufunc.reduce(array[indices[i]:indices[i+1]])

which means that `reduceat` goes over all indices in the given list and then slices the array performing the given `ufunc` on it (here it `add`s the numbers).

#### Ascending indices

This is pretty much and very well described by @Adarsh_V_Desai and also shown by @CT Zhu. Following the answers and the example:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(10) # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
indices = np.array([1,3,4,5])
```

In the first step of the loop, `i=1` and `i+1=3` hence we will get a slice `array[1:3]` which are elements `1, 2` which sums to 3. Then we get a slice from `i=3` to `i+1=4` which is just one element, `3`. The same for the next, again one element, `4`. Lastly, we get from `i=5` till the end because there is no other index (recall docs:

> for the last index, indices[i+1] = array.shape[axis]`),

that yields `array[5:]` and elements `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` which sums to 35.

#### Descending indices

The question came what happens when we have not ascending or descending indices. The principle works the same and will build up the way to the original example in the question. Let's have that example:

```py
np.add.reduceat([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7])
```

As shown above, it starts with `i=0` to `i+1=4`, ie. it takes the first 4 elements and returns their sum, `0+1+2+3=6`. Now it takes `i=4` to `i+1=1` which is, as mentioned in the comments, yielding `[]` if tried. But again, recall the docs:

> if indices[i] >= indices[i + 1], the i-th generalized “row” is simply array[indices[i]]

which means that we simply get the one element, ie. `4`. After that we again continue as in the first case and sum the 4 elements, then again give one row = one element, `5`, etc.

#### Why [::2]

As already probably seen from the example above, we get the linear ascend, then a jump when we need to return from `4` to `1`. We get the individual elements because we have the descending jumps in the list of indexes. And that is exactly what the `[::2]` is removing -> it is taking only every second element and since we have those jumps every second position, we remove them from the result.

#### 2D array

You have not asked but I believe it also works mentioning (since I also struggled at the beginning with this one).

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 16).reshape(4,4)
np.add.reduceat(x, [0, 3, 1, 2, 0])
array([[12.,  15.,  18.,  21.],
       [12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
       [ 4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [ 8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [24.,  28.,  32.,  36.]])
```

What this horrible creature does is the exact same thing as what is described above. First, it takes indices (rows!) from `i=0` to `i+1=3`, that is

```py
[ 0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
[ 4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
[ 8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
```

sums them and puts them into the first row (you can check). Then it hits a jump, hence you get just a row, namely the 4th row. Then it gives you the sum of rows `1:2` which is only the second row, so you get that one. Then there is another jump from `i=2` to `i+1=0`, which is again just one row, in this case, the 3rd. Lastly, it gives a sum of all rows since you go from
`0` to the end.

I won't go over columns (`axis=1`) since it's exactly the same. Hope it helps.